# Get value from `Tkinter.Entry` and compare its content with another value

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have the `__init__` function construct a `Tkinter` window. Inside the window there is a multiplication 5 * 10 and an `Entry` box. If the user fills the box with the right answer and presses the button afterwards, the `result` function is executed, which should have the label show the "right" message. Otherwise the label shows the "wrong" message.

The problem is: Even if the answer is right, the label shows the "wrong" message. If I print the `self.content` in the `result` function, it shows the right value in the terminal. But the problem is inside the `if` statement of the `result` function.

```
from Tkinter import *

class prop:

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        self.x = 5
        self.y = 10

        self.title = Label(self.root, text = "TEST")
        self.title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=6)
        self.title.config(font=("Courier", 30))

        self.labelx = Label(self.root,text=self.x)
        self.labelx.grid(row=2, column=2)
        self.labelx.config(font=("Courier", 30))

        self.epi = Label(self.root,text="X")
        self.epi.grid(row=2, column=3)
        self.epi.config(font=("Courier", 30))

        self.labely = Label(self.root,text=self.y)
        self.labely.grid(row=2, column=4)
        self.labely.config(font=("Courier", 30))

        self.total = Entry(self.root, font = "Courier 25 bold",justify="center",width=3)
        self.total.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=20)

        button = Button(self.root, text="OK", command = self.result)
        button.grid(row=3, column=2)

        self.content = Entry.get(self.total)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def result(self):
        if self.content == (self.x * self.y):
            self.labres = Label(self.root, text="Right")
            self.labres.grid(row=2, column=6)
            self.labres.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        else:
            self.labres = Label(self.root, text="Wrong")
            self.labres.grid(row=2, column=6)
            self.labres.config(font=("Courier", 30))


start = prop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the content of Entry before the value is entered.  You should read the content after the button has been clicked.

Also you are comparing string with int in `self.content == (self.x * self.y)`. You should use `int(self.content) == (self.x * self.y)`.

The updated result function is:

```
def result(self):
        self.content = Entry.get(self.total)
        if int(self.content) == (self.x * self.y):
            self.labres = Label(self.root, text="Right")
            self.labres.grid(row=2, column=6)
            self.labres.config(font=("Courier", 30))
        else:
            self.labres = Label(self.root, text="Wrong")
            self.labres.grid(row=2, column=6)
            self.labres.config(font=("Courier", 30))
```

Comment: if i do: if int(self.content) i get: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: @Athon  Please make sure `self.content` is not empty or does not contain any alphabets or symbols. You need to validate `self.content` before using it in `int(self.content)`

Comment: can you explain me what you mean to validate before?